# CUPS: Centralized CUPS server; how do I do this?

Tags: debian, networking, cups, printer

I have a printer 'brother'. My network is a linux server; 'server' (debian 8.5) that handles DHCP, DNS, Routing, Firewalling etc with a local address of 10.0.0.10. brother is connected to server and has an ip address of 10.0.0.90.

The clients on my network that have addresses of 10.0.0.x/24 are able to send jobs to the printer using ipp://10.0.0.90, however this requires each client to install cups and the driver or ppd for that printer. What I actually want to do is have clients send jobs to a centralized CUPS server at 10.0.0.10 and then that instance of CUPS has a master job list and sends that to the printer as one connection. I don't want to give direct access to 10.0.0.90.

I am confused on how to set this up exactly. Does anyone have any good resources I can read up on, or perhaps you can help me work this out?

Cheers!

llldino

Answer (score 0):

Set up `CUPS` on the central server.

Use `http://localhost:631`, the `Administration` tab, to Add the network printer, select driver, etc.

Use `http://localhost:631`, the `Administration` tab, to select `Share printers`.

Restart `CUPS` and `dnsmasq`, or reboot the server.

Configure the clients `http://localhost:631` on the clients, or read `man lpadmin`.